# Avoiding externalized tikz images to recompile after an image is inserted

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, externalize

I am sorry if this question has already been answered ( I searched thoroughly but could not find anything) and if my description leaks information (it's my first post and imho a MWE will not be beneficial).

So, I am working on my PhD thesis which includes a lot of images generated from Matlab using the matlab2tikz function. Due to time & memory saving reasons, I am using the \tikzexternalize command and the typical settings:

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=TIKZPDF/]
```

The image is included in a standard way:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\setlength\figureheight{6cm} 
\setlength\figurewidth{6cm} 
\input{TIKZ/examplefig.tikz}
\caption{example caption.}
\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
```

The externalized pictures are stored as .pdf files, named thesis-figure0, thesis-figure1 etc. up to more than a hundred (currently; a lot more to come).
Now here is the issue: When I include a new image in between the others, e.g. as thesis-figure22, everything from 23 to the end will recompile which takes several minutes (at least). This is caused by the fact that obviously, the numbering shifts from 22 onwards by 1 each so the image appears changed for the externalize-changes-checking-tool. However, the images aren't changed but only the indexing is shifted.
As waiting for all the figures to be compiled over and over is quite annoying and time-consuming, I would appreciate any hints on how to avoid this (with low effort / changes at best).

Thank you!

Comment: There is an open feature request on PGF/TikZ to use the content hash as the file name instead of a counter, which would allow reordering and deduplication of figures even across different documents. https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/758

Comment: There are several ways to work with all the media involved in a large document, in my case I limit myself to having all my tikz drawings precompiled in PDF format, and only include them using `\includegraphics[width=\wpf,height=\hpf]{TKZ-MEDIA/tkz_draw.pdf}` All images are imported as vectors without differences and saves me time.

Comment: Thanks so far. @HenriMenke so this means there is no solution currently (except for the \tikzsetnextfilename{⟨file name⟩} as suggested on github?) this means somewhat more effort but still better than compiling for ages. @J Leon V: There's an issue with automatically set colormaps etc. and sometimes I have to make changes to existing figures which is a lot more convenient when the tikz is directly included.